# How to upload video to dropbox without authentication

Tags: python-2.7, video, dropbox

Iam new to Dropbox/python pls guide me accordingly.

I need to build simple userinterface(web) where i should have option to upload .mp4 files to dropbox. Using python i need to read the video from dropbox and store the images in dropbox folder. The webinterface should not ask for authentication to upload into Dropbox.

Please suggest how can enduser from internet upload videos into dropbox without authentication.

I had gone thru dropbox API but i could not get anything relavant. Pls suggest

Comment: I strongly believe that it's impossible to store some files in someone's dropbox **without** authentication

Comment: Any other options available pls

Comment: Do you mean maybe that you want to upload to your own Dropbox account without having the end-user authenticate with Dropbox?